How do you get to 32 using only 12345
Only addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division
Need to do it in order 5 4 3 2 1
You can use parenthesis

What does "need to do it in order $54321$" mean?

I see a solution, but would like the know the source of this puzzle before posting an answer.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!  Please let us know whether you created this puzzle by yourself OR tell us where you learned about this puzzle.  Thanks!

Solution here:

 5*(4+3)-2-1

 test: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=5*%284%2B3%29-2-1


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

@bobble Have you considered voting to close it so that such answers can't be posted in the first place?

@F1Krazy Yes? I'm not sure what the implication is supposed to be? I'm busy in real life and don't see every question immediately, nor do I immediately vote to close every off-topic question, since the community sees that as unwelcoming.

Well, it is so trivial that don't need attribution, everyone can "compose" such a question. Even if found here https://www.mersenneforum.org/node/16168 , with 39 there are other sources.
